# How to setup IMAP in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, imap

How can I setup IMAP in CodeIgniter. For now, I'm using just pure php. But I need to change as CodeIgniter Standard. Please help me. Here is my IMAP Setup with Pure php

```
// Connect to gmail
                    $hostname = '{imap.gmail.com:993/ssl/novalidate-cert}[Gmail]/All Mail';
                    $username = 'my email';
                    $password = 'my password';
```

Comment: you need to provide more information about IMAP configuration in your application.

Comment: IMAP is not well-documented.You will need to setup the email.php config file.

Comment: I don't know how to make config file? Can u guide me please? I'm noob

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like this, make some changles as per your needs and add this as a function in your controller.
If you need more help give us a sample od your code from controller and view.

```
<?php
    $mbox = imap_open("{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}", "me mail", "my password");

    echo "<h1>Mailboxes</h1>\n";
    $folders = imap_listmailbox($mbox, "{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}", "*");

    if ($folders == false) {
        echo "Call failed<br />\n";
    } else {
        foreach ($folders as $val) {
            echo $val . "<br />\n";
        }
    }

    echo "<h1>Headers in INBOX</h1>\n";
    $headers = imap_headers($mbox);
    arsort($headers);

    if ($headers == false) {
        echo "Call failed<br />\n";
    } else {
        foreach ($headers as $val) {
            echo $val . "<br />\n";
        }
    }

    imap_close($mbox);
    ?>
```